# Curl request to http://www.google.com not working though ping to the ip address works in HDP sandbox

Tags: curl, virtualbox, wget, sandbox, hortonworks-data-platform

While I am trying to ping any ip address from HDP sandbox 2.4 (which is running on Oracles virtual box )I am able to do that but when I  run curl or wget command it doesnt work. It says Couldn't resolve host 'www.google.com'.